# How to use ConstraintLayout normally and correctly?

Tags: java, android, layout, mobile-development

I've got some problem with my android layout, and i've got tired of trying to solve this. I've got TabView, PageViewer and two buttons, but PageViewer covers other interface elements with its container, so pages are shown uncorrectly. How can I put PageViewer between tabs and buttons, so it would fit that without covering any other ui elements. Here's my code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/scheduleDaySelector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/scheduleViewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/menu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scheduleDaySelector" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/scheduleViewer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/scheduleButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/schedule_button"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule_button"
            app:iconGravity="textStart" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/announcementButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/announcement_button"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_announcement_button"
            app:iconGravity="textStart" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried attaching the top and bottom of the PageViewer to the bottom of the TabView and the top of the button leyout, but nothing changed and the problem persisted. I've been trying to solve this problem for an hour now, please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your bottom constraint for `menu` should be

```xml
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

instead of

```xml
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/scheduleViewer"
```

And the layout width/height of `scheduleViewer` should be 0dp

```xml
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

(So they'll stretch instead of being the entire size of the parent)